# Not able to connect to oracle database using context variables talend open studio for Big Data

Tags: oracle, talend

[image]

I had created context group: [image: context group] using context variables for database connection imported from Oracle db connections in meta data.

While running the job it is throwing the following error:

```
Exception in component tOracleInput_1
java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: Io exception: Invalid number format for port number
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.SQLStateMapping.newSQLException(SQLStateMapping.java:101)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.newSQLException(DatabaseError.java:112)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:173)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:229)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:458)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:411)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:490)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:202)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:33)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:465)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at local_project.praba_test_demo_2_0_1.praba_test_demo_2.tOracleInput_1Process(praba_test_demo_2.java:757)
[statistics] disconnected
    at local_project.praba_test_demo_2_0_1.praba_test_demo_2.runJobInTOS(praba_test_demo_2.java:1297)
    at local_project.praba_test_demo_2_0_1.praba_test_demo_2.main(praba_test_demo_2.java:1084)
Job praba_test_demo_2 ended at 14:37 15/12/2016. [exit code=1][enter image description here][1]
```

Comment: The error seems to be with the port variable :
- what is the type of your port context variable ? (integer , string)
- What is the given value ? You can try to change the type between integer/string .
Could you add a screenshot of the settings of tOracleInput_1 ?

Answer (score 1):

I can see all the context are written within quotes (" "), remove the quotes and write the context like context.<>.

If still does not work, please check if this number is correct.Have you tried connecting to Oracle SQL editor with same properties? Is it getting connected?